# Mocha throws an error when no tests are found. Can this be suppressed?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I'm running Mocha on the command line like this:

```
mocha --recursive "./src/**/*.spec.js"
```

This works great. However, if no test files are found, it throws this error:

```
cannot resolve path (or pattern) './src/**/*.spec.js'
```

Is there a way to suppress this error message **when no tests exist**?

(To clarify, this is relevant because it's part of my [React Slingshot starter kit](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot), so no tests will exist after they delete my example tests to begin their project).

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue and was reported several times, e.g. [here](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/2380) or [here](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/pull/2001). The most relevant GitHub issue is this [feature request](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/2194) that [replaces](https://github.com/gurdiga/mocha/commit/33de79eb65c64ac354ae0ac169e388ed55875528) error with a more descriptive message. Hopefully this PR will be merged soon.

For now, you can include a shell script in your starter kit that will execute the mocha test runner only if test files are present.

**test.sh** (needs Bash 4.0 or newer for globstar support)

```
#!/bin/bash

count=`ls -1 src/**/*.spec.js -name 'Prams' -type d 2> /dev/null | wc -l`

if [ "$count" -gt "0" ]; then
    npm run test:mocha --silent
else
    echo -e "\033[0;31mWrite some tests!" && exit 1
fi
```

**package.json**

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "./test.sh",
    "test:mocha": "mocha 'src/**/*.spec.js'"
  },
```

Unfortunately this won't work with glob braced sections - mocha will throw an error even if there are some tests available in on of the directories but the first directory in set is empty.